# CSV Type provider

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-interactive, f#-data

I am trying to find a easy example or introduction to a CSV Type provider. So I followed this [link](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html) to help me get started. Now I have a Visual Studio 2012 students edition and while documentation says that F# 3.0 has the CSV type provider I am not able to find it. So I am trying to use a type provider for a local CSV File. What I see is that the CSV TypeProvider mentioned does not exist at all. Since the given examples don't really compile I looked around and used something like this to load the oData services :

```
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders"
///loading a stackoverflow odata type provider
type stackOverflow = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.ODataService<"http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom">
```

So this is a bit different from what is mentioned in the example page above. I am not able to see the csv type provider. I use the Visual Studio IDE to list the type providers and csv is not listed. I tried updating the packages using nuget and this still persists. Can anyone point the right documentation on how to work with a csv type provider and also the right updated links where a simple example could be found?

Comment: You're missing `open FSharp.Data`

Comment: I have already tried that, the Visual Studio does not recognize it if I add FSharp.Data as a reference . So I used the Nuget load the packages. But I don't want to use Nuget to reference it all the time. Is there any other way to include references from another project? Where do the F# libraries exist if I had to write a reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FSharp.Data isn't a built-in library, so you either need to use nuget or manually download the package.  See [here](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) for more information on where to get it (and how to use it).

If you manually download the project you can put it wherever you want and then simply use a file path to reference it with `#r`.  For a path relative to your project, use the `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` symbol, otherwise you can simply use the absolute file path of the .dll.

After referencing the dll, you still need to open the namespace, so you need to have `open FSharp.Data` after you reference the dll.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this is what I did. I used Nuget to manage references and I installed the FSharp.Data and FSharp.Data.TypeProviders and like @mydogisbox mentioned I then use the open FSharp.Data to load the csv files i.e.

```
open FSharp.Data.Csv
```

While this works if I use Nuget, it doesn't work otherwise. So have to figure out how to do that. For now this should suffice I guess.

Comment: The CsvProvider is actually in the `FSharp.Data` namespace. `FSharp.Data.Csv` contains the non-type provider pieces like the parser, etc...